# UHF transmitter Range for 50 W

Tags: radar, radio, antenna

Very curious to know the range of 50 W transmitter of UHF range in nautical miles? The antenna used is 1/4 wave antenna of Jaybeam company. Can someone tell the exact formulation to find out the answer? Just to add further, height of Tx and Rx antenna is around 60 meters.

Comment: Is thin on aircraft? Or urban area? Open land? What's the exact gain in dBi of the antenna? How about the length and losses of the coaxial cable powering the antenna? What modulation type are you using? What's the receive sensitivity of the receivers? We need a lot more info to make this question answerable and a lot more context, if we need to assume.

Comment: The transmitter of the Mariner IV spacecraft, that relayed the first shots of Mars taken from an interplanetary probe, had a power of 10 watts...

Comment: Range is meaningless without knowledge of the receiver - an EM wave will carrry on until infinity gradually blending in with the background noise of space. Question is under-constrained.

Comment: 50 W is +47 dBm.  A 1 GHz signal with LOS 80 km the range loss is 130 dB. Ignoring antenna gains, the received signal power is ~ -83 dBm. This is ok for AM modulated voice.

Comment: Hey D Duck how you calculated the horizon?

Comment: Wikipedia says it all https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon but there are online calculators for this sort of stuff. You need also to assume that the Earth is not flat.

Comment: D Duck please explain what u said above... @D Duck

Comment: What SNR will you tolerate? 18dB for acceptable FM voice? or 0dB for acceptable MorseCode in 10Hz bandwidth? Thus the modulation must be specified.

Comment: No satisfactory answer so far !!!

Comment: @Rumi, I believe there is a satisfactory answer given. Please explain what you think is missing.

Answer (score 1):

The horizon is ~ 30 km away if you're 60 m tall. So you expect a line of sight of 60 km.  And then with refraction (for UHF) you get abut 1/3 more so about 80 km.

80 km = 43 nautical miles.

Comment: How do certain frequencies refract more than others?  Interaction with moisture?

Comment: Link to website about VHF/UHF/Microwave Radio Propagation https://www.tapr.org/ve3jf.dcc97.html

Comment: How did you conclude that you would get a 1/3 more at UHF? Most articles I've read say that beyond 30 MHz the game is up for ionospheric reflection.

Comment: 4/3 factor is the "earth bulge" or "effective radius" of the earth and a refraction effect. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-of-sight_propagation http://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Effective_earth_radius

Comment: Horizon is an important issue.  How much beyond that you can go depends on things like temperature-driven ducting along the curve of the earth, or flukes like meteor ionization trails, as normally UHF would not be reflected by the ionosphere.  And of course the earth isn't barren and round, especially in interesting areas.  Power comes in to play when there's a marginal path, or interference, but by 50 watts most of what is achievable is probably achieved.